# jquery show/hide divs and a counter

Tags: jquery, html, list, loops

I have a random amount of DIVs (minimum 1, max of 10)

```
<div id="container">
<div class="foo">Content</div> <!-- div 1 -->
<div class="foo">Content</div> <!-- div 2 -->
<div class="foo">Content</div> <!-- div 3 -->
<div class="foo">Content</div> <!-- div 4 -->
<div class="foo">Content</div> <!-- div 5 -->
<div class="foo">Content</div> <!-- i need this one hidden -->
<div class="foo">Content</div> <!-- and this one -->
</div>
```

I want the first 5 divs to be visible (either with .show() or with a class, doesn't matter). Any additional DIVs should be hidden.

I then simulate the "closing" of a div with:

```
$('.foo').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');    
});
```

which removes the clicked div, causing all the divs below to move up one. This is my desired effect.

However, I need some logic here.

If I have less than 5 DIVS, the close facility should be disabled. If I have more than 5 DIVs, then when a div is "closed", i want the next "hidden" div to become visible.

I can add IDs to each DIV if required with IDs like "foo1" "foo2" etc.

Comment: Nick Craver's solution is a nice one.  I just want to note that using `slideDown` and `slideUp` where you're using `fadeOut/In` makes a nice effect with less jerkiness.

Comment: advice heeded, much prettier !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("#container .foo:gt(4)").hide();

$("#container").delegate(".foo", "click", function() {
    if(!$("#container .foo:hidden").length) return;
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() { 
        $(this).siblings(":hidden:first").fadeIn()
               .end().remove();
    });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/A5cAH/).  What this does is hides all past 5 using the [`:gt(4)`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) (0-based) selector.  Then we're using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for efficiency (though a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) would work too).  If there aren't any more hidden, there's no effect.  If there *are* more hidden, fade out the one we clicked, at at the end of the fade show the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) [`:hiddden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) one, and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the one we faded out completely.

Comment: or ugly css! .foo+.foo+.foo+.foo+.foo+.foo { display: none; } anything with more than 5 preceding .foo siblings will get hidden. if you remove it anyway. it doesnt have the fadeIn support though

Comment: @DoXicK - I think you overlooked the `.end()` call, it's not the fadeing-in sibling I'm removing, it's `$(this)` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.foo').each(
   function(index,element) {
       if(index>5) $(element).hide();
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#container div.foo').click(function() {
  if ($(this).index() >= 5) ...; //etc
}
```

Comment: if you have a thousand results, you will be executing that function a thousand times. what about using :gt(4) in combination with a direct hide() ? it's way faster

Comment: But we dont, we have max 10 as the OP stated - and we have the ability to modify the code based on each index... anyway